# Can't change tenant till login to host

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Once my webpage is deployed in IIS it seems that i am unable to properly switch tenants until i log into the default/host first. I don't want to require my users to have to do this before being allowed to switch to the tenant. It seems like the view is not properly being updated but i'm not sure why.  I am using the ASP boilerplate template as a base and have not changed any of the login code/functionality at all.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: is it MVC core?

Comment: it is not mvc core, and i finally tracked down what is occurring. the cookie in the storage was being updated, however the document.cookie for the site was not being updated. I updated the javascript to set the critical cookie value i need for the tenant and it appears to be functioning properly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tracked down the issue. For some reason when it goes to set the document.cookie value that includes the path and expire along with the tenant ID for whatever reason the browser is not updating the document.cookie with the according values. The javascript itself is not failing.

The fix is to just set the tenant portion of the cookie by itself and it works. Maybe someone can explain this behavior, but i tested the string and it will update the cookie just fine if i have logged into a tenant or host first.

Just seems once the session times out or is marked as bad this issue comes up.